# Inserting keyframes from node editor is not working

Tags: animation, node-editor, keyframes, opengl

I followed the following post to try keyframing assigned material to an object 
[blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64986/keyframe-objects-active-material-from-material-slots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64986/keyframe-objects-active-material-from-material-slots)
I followed the steps mentioned there exactly and got the same results, however when i insert keyframes for any value in any node i get no keyframes in timeline or fcurves, only there are keyframes in dope sheet, and no animation could be run in the viewport. I'm currently in blender render, and i wanna run it only in the viewport, i don't need to render it using blender render.

Comment: In the header of the graph editor and dopesheet, there is a button with a cursor on it, curves will only display for a selected node while this is highlighted. How complex are the materials? Is it just a colour change or a texture change?

Comment: just a color change, exactly the same as the above link. it turned out that, as you said, curves are displayed after i select a node. however, color changes are only displayed in viewport when i drag the factor slider, as seen in the link, but when i play animation, nothing changes in viewport

Comment: after some search, i thought that node changes can't be rendered in viewport using opengl,  however, it does render in viewport with opengl, as i told you, only if i drag the slider in a node, bout doesn't work when playing animation in timeline. i wonder why ??  by the way it only works when i render using blender render

Comment: I think it is a limitation of the material nodes and is most likely related to the dependancy graph. Changing the node value updates the viewport but changing the frame doesn't read the keyed values from nodes.

Answer (score 1):

As you only want to change the basic colour, you can key the diffuse colour value instead of using nodes, this is a more reliable way to have the 3Dview updated.

[image: keyed colour]

Like other values you can hover the mouse over the colour and press <kbd>I</kbd> or right click<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on it and choose Insert Keyframe. A border is added to the colour swatch to show the keyed status.